# How to make a interactive command in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am wondering how in discord.js to make a interactive giveaway command like the giveaway bot

**I am in V11/12**
For example when I do g!giveaway start, it starts a interactive setup what will work like this

The bot will say 
"Time"

Then I set the type it will last with variables (m for minutes, d for days, w for weeks)

Then it will say

"Okay! Now what do you want to giveaway?"

Then I just say what I want to giveaway

And then it will say

"Great! What channel will the giveaway be in?"

Then I put the channel

Then the bot says

"Good! The giveaway for (prize) has started in (channel) and will last (time) seconds/days/weeks

**Please can I get some help here, thanks!**

Comment: Please provide what you did so far.

Comment: I have not started as I need to know like how to make an interactive setup

Comment: Try it yourself! It is extremely educational and satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

**Send a message and await a response using a collector (awaitMessages)**

We will want to wait for a message after asking, so we will use a collector.

Async `TextChannel.awaitMessages()` ([read docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)) can be used to collect messages. It needs a filter to know which messages to accept, as well as some options to know when to stop collecting.

```js
// accepted messages will be those from the same author, we compare IDs to make sure
const filter = msg => msg.author.id == message.author.id;

// the only option needed will be maxMatches, to only take one message before ending the collector
const options = {
  maxMatches: 1
};
```

The collector will then return a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of messages, we will always be taking `.first()` since there will only be one, and store its content.

```js
// assuming you have the `channel` object, and are inside an async function
let collector = await channel.awaitMessages(filter, options);
let answer = collector.first().content;
```

Use the above after every `channel.send()` for each different answer you're looking from the user.

**Example on how to use the Collector**

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.content === "!color") {
    // request
    message.channel.send("What's your fav color?");

    // collector
    let collector = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options);
    let answer = collector.first().content;

    // response
    await message.reply("your fav color is " + answer + "!");
  }
});
```

Note that this is just an example and in a real implementation you must handle errors properly. Here's the example result:

[image: Color command example]

If you need more inputs just create more collectors and answers, and do with that information however you need to.

Comment: Is there any way I could get an example of this working within a command?

Comment: I've added an example on the post.

Comment: It does work but how do I get it to work with two, as I tried that and it did not work with two.

Comment: Create another collector `collector1` to get `answer1`, and if you need more, `collector2` to get `answer2` and so on. Before each one you'll send a message to ask the question. Make sure to use `await` before each async statement to not mess up the order.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, now is there any way you know how to make a giveaway command?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MessageCollectors. For example:

```js
let opt = {
    prize: null, 
    time: null
};
message.channel.send("Whats the prize?");
let collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, () => true);
collector.on("collect", (m) => {
    if(opt.prize && !opt.time){
       opt.time = m.content;
       message.channel.send("Giveaway started! (prize:"+opt.prize+", time:"+opt.time+")");
       collector.stop();
    }
    if(!opt.prize && !opt.time){
         opt.prize = m.content;
         message.channel.send("ok! So what's the time?");
    }
});
```

You can add as many opt as you want, follow the same logic.
You can use [my npm package, discord-giveaways](https://npmjs.com/discord-giveaways) to create giveaways easily.

Comment: No errors but overall, did not really do what I wanted it to do.